# Django Api url conflicting whenever i apply the url of the app into the urlpatterns and i don't know the way forword here

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-auth

So, whenever i add this path('api/', include('api.urls')) into the parent urls i get a bunch of errors in the terminal and if i remove it from the urlpatterns i get page not found wheni reload the localhost on my browser, and on the terminal page it shows "Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 8441)" and i'm really really confused right now.

Api urls

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()

router.register('users', views.UserViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Parent Urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

Errors

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\songcrud\api\urls.py", line 2, in <module>      
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\songcrud\api\views.py", line 13, in <module>    
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CRUD\songcrud\api\views.py", line 15, in UserViewSet 
    default_serializer_class = serializers.UserOutputSerializer
AttributeError: module 'api.serializers' has no attribute 'UserOutputSerializer'. Did you mean: 'UserInputSerializer'?
```

this is what i get from the browser when this is removed `path('api/', include('api.urls'))`

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in songcrud.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    api-auth/

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Maybe i'm the one getting it wrong please help me,

Here is my views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .permissions import IsCreatorOrAdminReadOnly
from . import serializers
# Create your views here.

UserModel = get_user_model()


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    default_serializer_class = serializers.UserOutputSerializer

    serializers_classes = {
        "create": serializers.UserInputSerializer
    }

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        User SignUp
            - Allow anyone to signup (without authentication)
        """
        self.check_permissions(request)
        serializer = serializers.UserInputSerializer(data=request.POST)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            email=serializer.validated_data["email"],
            first_name=serializer.validated_data["first_name"],
            last_name=serializer.validated_data["last_name"],
            password=serializer.validated_data["password"]
        )
        response = serializers.UserInputSerializer(user).data
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'create':  # Create, List, Retrieve, Update, or Destory
            permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        elif self.action in ['update', 'partial_update', 'destroy']:
            permission_classes = [
                IsCreatorOrAdminReadOnly, permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        elif self.action == 'list':
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
        else:
            permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]

        return super().get_permissions()
```

Comment: The last part of your Errors seems truncated, can you repaste please?

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'api.serializers' has no attribute 'UserOutputSerializer'. Did you mean: 'UserInputSerializer'?` The api/serializers.py file appears to be one you wrote - does it have a class called UserOutputSerializer?